# Build process successful but ClickOnce executable fails, visual studio 2013 solution migration

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-installer, clickonce

I am a complete noob when it comes to anything visual studio.  I was passed down an old and dusty solution written with c# and vs2008.  In my supreme lack of wisdom I got a trial version of vs 2013 ultimage (full working version - 90days) and managed to get the solution to build 'successfully' however the executable generated in the build process does not run, in fact it fails instantly and silently.  The click once executable fails but generates an output manifest saying that it is missing my 'ProjectNameHere.ico.deploy' file which it also tried to download before failing.

The solution contains 10 projects that all depend on one another in some way that I'm sure the original dev understood just fine.  I would like to package all 10 into an msi to send to a colleague for testing at some point.

I am more then happy to send log files or anything else to someone that has some expertise, also any reading or info that might help for trouble shooting this problem would be greatly appreciated.  I completely understand if this question is a little out there and I will be monitoring this post closely to update any details in question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Click the Debug option. Does that work fine?

Answer (score 0):

You mention build but not publish? Also you want an MSI. [ClickOnce deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.120).aspx) doesn't use MSIs, it uses a completely different setup of its own, which you create by publishing the app to a deployment location such as a web page, file share or other media.

So rather than looking for an executable created by the build, you should publish the app, and then install from the deployment location. After the publish, this location will contain all the files needed for the ClickOnce deployment.

To do this, after a successful build right-click the main project and choose Publish. You then get to choose your preferred deployment location. Once the publish completes, install from the deployment location.